# The verb "shift" + prep

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I saw a sentence that has the word shift.  I am trying to understand the sentence but it has become hard to understand.

The sentence is

> Over the past few years **shifts in** educational policies have affected society especially in developed nations.

I am not quite sure how the "shift" is used in this content. I can see it is used as a verb but why there is a proposition of "in"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word is actually used as a noun here, not a verb.

As Maulik mentions, a "shift" is a change.  While *shift* and *change* are very close in meaning, *shift* is a little more specific word than *change*, because it generally has the sense of changing or exchanging one thing for another.  In your sentence, one set of policies is replaced by another.

Answer (score 1):

The word `shift` has several meanings but here, we can think of its general meaning of 'change' **in** something.

That said, over the past few years, the ***changes in*** educational policies have affected societies.

You can look up in any dictionary and find the word 'shift' meaning 'change'.